How is a question about the "self" a duplicate of a question about "consciousness"?
Question about self: Is the notion of a "self" that persists over time an illusion?
Question about consciousness: Is there any coherent argument in support of consciousness being an illusion?
My own argument:

@JD If consciousness is an illusion, there is no consciousness. My question is not asking whether consciousness is an illusion, but whether the "self" is an illusion. There could be consciousness and the self might still be an illusion. I'd be happy to grant the duplicate charge if you can prove that the self exists if and only if consciousness exists.

A supporting comment:

@JD the concept of a self does not have to correspond with consciousness. Do babies have the feeling of being a subject? –
Syed


I’m voting to close this question because it's not asking a meta question. There is currently a mechanism for closing/reopening questions. If the proposal is to change this mechanism, that's a different issue.

I believe that the self is an evolved form of consciousness. So if you ask the question about the "self" then consciousness is part of the question. That's why I believe its a duplicate.

@IdiosyncraticSoul Would you like to write an answer to What's the difference (if any) between "self" and "consciousness"??

No There is an entire section of Infant Psychology and Development that deals with self-awareness. Sure. It's a philosophy question too, but psychology includes empirical evidence  .

They are not duplicates, but it's not primarily because of a distinction between "self" and "consciousness," which one could reasonably argue are strongly linked, if not the same.
Rather, your question is about the persistence or continuity of consciousness/self. Whether consciousness can be continuously traced over time is a different question from whether it is an illusion. A reasonable position is that consciousness suffers a discontinuity when you go to sleep, and thus one stretch of it ends, but that it is not illusory as long as it is present.
So, yes, they are not duplicates. If you get 4 reopen votes and tag me, I'll be 5th.

That was the edit, not the original question.

4 reopen votes ;)

From Google's definition of self:

a person's essential being that distinguishes them from others, especially considered as the object of introspection or reflexive action.

So, yes, on a canonical reading, the self is a product of self-consciousness. Note, the original question was something along the lines of "Is the self an illusion?". Since the "self" and "self-awareness" and "consciousness" are all intimately related in philosophy of mind, the questions were close enough to warrant my personal VTC.
Here me and some of the other contributors will part ways. You are not looking for a canonical, fact-based answer to a fact-seeking question. You are looking to provoke a philosophical debate over the self, consciousness, and what it means to be illusory. If the question is reopened, I'm not going to lose any sleep, but a canonical response in the analytic tradition would simply point out that both the experience of consciousness and the self are properties of a mind. Both 'consciousness' and 'self' are terms so contested and intertwined, that there's an entire article in the SEP that covers the overlap: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/self-consciousness/

Human beings are conscious not only of the world around them but also of themselves: their activities, their bodies, and their mental lives. They are, that is, self-conscious (or, equivalently, self-aware). Self-consciousness can be understood as an awareness of oneself. But a self-conscious subject is not just aware of something that merely happens to be themselves, as one is if one sees an old photograph without realising that it is of oneself. Rather a self-conscious subject is aware of themselves as themselves; it is manifest to them that they themselves are the object of awareness. Self-consciousness is a form of consciousness that is paradigmatically expressed in English by the words “I”, “me”, and “my”, terms that each of us uses to refer to ourselves as such.

SELF-consciousness is the source of SELF, which is why rocks don't have selves, biographies full of identity-based facts don't have selves, and trees don't have selves. (And no, plants aren't conscious by standard definitions either). Perhaps you've differentiated the question, but the idea the self is anything other than a product of self-CONSCIOUSNESS would be a stretch.
I don't have a problem pointing out that your questions are engaged in some metaphysical hairsplitting worthy of the Scholastics. Personally, I presume that you're part of some secret initiative to generate additional questions without much thought to boost metrics of one type or another. For the sake of the I-want-to-do philosophy crowd, I hope your question is reopened. But for the we're-here-to-provide-references-to-the-canon crowd, it seems reasonable to close any question that doesn't seem well thought out, well researched, or is the product of mere boredom at work.

"You are not looking for a canonical, fact-based answer to a fact-seeking question" - How is a question about the fundamental nature of the "self" and its persistence over time (or lack thereof) not a question about facts, that is seeking fact-based answers?

How about this question: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/120939/80226?

@user80226 Because 'self' is essentially contested. Perhaps some philosophers have views of the self that might form the basis of that answer,  but I doubt such views are held in isolation from the concept of self-consciousness.

The height of the Empire State Building as well as its location are facts; deciphering a putative fact-based theory on the ontological status of the 'self' whatever that may be is in a different class of epistemological coherence given its reliance on so many abstracta. Dennstt's take is that existence and public access to empirical truth should  be preserved by heterophenomenological methods. Is the definition of 'self' eligible even?

As usual, your questions are being targeted due to others’ perceived annoyances of you, even though you often spend a lot of time adding further context to questions, which most on this site do not do.  “I don’t like you” is not a valid reason to close your question, no matter how many people on this site persistently think like this. I also urge you to not fall prey to their tactics even if they downvote.
With that being said, the self is not the same as being conscious even if they’re related. Books spanning millennia in Buddhist teachings talk about how the entire concept of a self is not real and that consciousness is pure. There are animals that are conscious that do not recognize themselves in front of the mirror, including babies. Whether or not you agree with this, it is not a duplicate, although I do see 3 reopen votes, so it’ll probably be re opened.
